# Select each option in a drop down using Selenium WebDriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm not able to select options in a drop down list. I think I need to have `.Select` or `SelectElement`, but there is no such option.

Sample code:

```
IWebDriver ffbrowser = new FirefoxDriver();
ffbrowser.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.amazon.com/");
ffbrowser.Manage().Window.Maximize();

Thread.Sleep(500);

IWebElement ddl = ffbrowser.FindElement(By.Name("url"));
int numofitems = ddl.FindElements(By.TagName("option")).Count;

for (int i = 1; i < numofitems; i++)
{
    ffbrowser.select("TagName = option", "index = i");
}
```

The "select" in "ffbrowser.select" is reported as an error:

Error   1   'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver' does not contain a definition for 'select' and no extension method 'select' accepting a first argument of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My project references include `Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium`, `Thoughtworks.Selenium.Core`, `WebDriver`, `WebDriver.Support`

and I have

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
```

Comment: use the IDE Intellisense

Comment: using the Selenium IDE, it says there should be a select option, but It's not available in visual studio intellisense.

Comment: You have a FirefoxDriver so I assume you are using Selenium WebDriver and not the IDE.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Depending what version of Selenium WebDriver you are using you can use the `SelectElement` class, which will be included in `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI`. 
For example:

```
SelectElement selector = new SelectElement(element);
selector.SelectByIndex(1);
```

Where the *element* is your drop down box.

Comment: Don't forget to `install-package selenium.support`

Comment: @ChrisS Why is hard to find this clue.

Comment: Your question is to select each option - it means you want to select each option one by one not only one item. To select all options you need to use loop

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to better illustrate how to get all the items in a drop down list and to select an item from the drop down list.

A sample Html code for drop down list

```
<select>
  <option>Milk</option>
  <option>Coffee</option>
  <option>Tea</option>
</select>
```

Code below gets all the items from the drop down list above and selects item 'Coffee'.Logic of the code is as follows

Step 1. Create an interface of the web element  tag
Step 2. Create an IList with all the child elements of web element  tag
Step 3. Select the Drop List item "Coffee"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
    class DropDownListSelection
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://DropDownList.html");
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//Select"));
            IList<IWebElement> AllDropDownList =    element.FindElements(By.XPath("//option"));
            int DpListCount = AllDropDownList.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < DpListCount; i++)
            {
                if (AllDropDownList[i].Text == "Coffee")
                 {
                    AllDropDownList[i].Click();
                 }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(DpListCount);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems overly complicated compared to using the SelectElement class. Also, I have found in some cases that if the list is not expanded already, trying to 'click' an option leaves you clicking whitespace below the drop down list, which selects nothing.

Comment: Yes SelectElement class is the straight forward one for all the selection operations. However if you want cross check the contents in the DropDown list with your test data, before even starting to do the selection operations then  I think this one works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("")).SelectByText(""));
```

Or:

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("")).SelectByValue(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below simple sample code:

```
String Input="Value to Select"; 
String xPathVal="@["id=Samplexpath"]"; 
IWebElement TargetElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xPathVal)); 
SelectElement dropdown = new SelectElement(TargetElement); 
dropdown.SelectByText(Input.Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly ...

```
SelectElement selector = new SelectElement(element);
selector.SelectByIndex(1);
```

Where the element is your drop down box.