# Selenium webdriver (tested ChromeDriver) cant find option by text containing umlauts?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I have a dropdown which structure is this one:
[image]

Now, I want to use Selenium Webdriver to select the last option by text (I cannot rely on the option being the last one actually).

Trying this:

```
var text = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;undersida";

var option = new SelectElement(browser.FindElement(By
  .CssSelector("#Menu_ParentMenuID"))).SelectByText(text);
```

gives me a NoSuchElementException.

Why?

Here is the list of values I have tried for `text`:

> ```
> "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;undersida"
> "   undersida"
> "undersida"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still an issue, but i'd like to contribute.

I think the problem lies in the nature (or your understanding) of a "no-break space".
it is not a regular space like in " " or the string "`&nbsp;`"
what you actually want is the c# unicode representation of it

so the string to test should be something like:

```
"\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0undersida"
```

take a look here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
new Select(browser.findElement(By.css("#Menu_ParentMenuID")))
    .selectByVisibleText("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;undersida");
```

Comment: Where do I find the Select class?

Answer (score 0):

There is one other way to select the concerned element, if you are not bound by selecting by visible text only.

**Below is the Java code for that:**

```
        String str = "undersida";

        Select sel = new Select(browser.findElement(By.id("Menu_ParentMenuID")));
        List<WebElement> list_options = sel.getOptions();
        for(WebElement ele: list_options){
            if(ele.getText().contains(str)){
                String value = ele.getAttribute("value");
                sel.selectByValue(value);
                break;
            }
        }
```

This will get all the options from the **select dropdown**. Then search the option whose innerHTML/text contains the required one. Then, it gets the "value" attribute of that option. After that, it selects the concerned item from the dropdown using the value related to that text.

Comment: Where do I find the Select class?

Comment: From your code, I perceive you are using **C#** for coding. So, you can use **"SelectElement"** class, and this link might help for properly selecting using **SelectElement** : [http://stackoverflow.com/a/15535624/4193730](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15535624/4193730). Also, if you can formulate the above java code in C#, it will definitelywork.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:-

```
var option = new SelectElement(browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#Menu_ParentMenuID"))).SelectBySubText("undersida");
```